# How can I override a JFrame of the other Frames

Tags: java, swing, jframe, overlay

I would like to know how I can override a JFrame over all other frames, such as a popup. With setVisible, it appears, but behind the already open windows.

Comment: You mean, such as a JDialog?

Comment: Well, it would be like Popup for new skype message, it would appear in the corner and it would soon disappear, but it would not have OK button or anything, just show information. I do not know if you have how to do this in JDialog. [Example](http://i.imgur.com/ZM3qqfk.png).

Comment: Yes, a JDialog would work just fine.